# How to compare if System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush and Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ColorFormat has same color?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto

I have a VSTO application written in C#.Net.

In Powerpoint color of a Shape is defined by `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ColorFormat`

Ex: `Shape.Fill.ForeColor`

But I need to compare it with `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush`

Is there a proper way to compare the RGB values of them without any conversion issues in Alpha/Opacity etc?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ColorFormat` looks like it has a [RGB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/ff763796(v=office.12)) property of int-type. The name suggest this does not contain the alpha-component, but the documentation is lacking.

a SolidColorBrush have a Color property that can be used. Unfortunately the color does not seem to have a way to convert it to an int directly. You could either use the R, G, B, properties and shift them into the right place for an int. Or use System.Drawing.Color [FromArgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Color_FromArgb_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) and [ToArgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.toargb?view=net-5.0) to make it into an int. When doing the conversion you can chose to include the Alpha value or not.

In the end you should have two int values you can compare directly.